# PostgreSQL: improve the performance when counting the distinct

Tags: postgresql, performance, count, distinct

I am currently working on improving the performance of our db. And I need some help from you. 
I have a table and its index like this

```
CREATE TABLE public.ar
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    duration double precision,
    is_idle boolean NOT NULL,
    activity_id integer NOT NULL,
    device_id integer NOT NULL,
    calendar_id integer,
    on_taskness integer,
    week_id integer,
    some_other_column_below,
    CONSTRAINT id_ PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT a_unique_key UNIQUE (user_id, device_id, start_time_local, start_time_utc, end_time_local, end_time_utc)
)

CREATE INDEX ar_idx
    ON public.ar USING btree
    (week_id, calendar_id, user_id, activity_id, duration, on_taskness, is_idle)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Then I am trying to run a query like this

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT ar.user_id
    FROM ar
    WHERE ar.user_id = ANY(array[some_data]) -- data size is 352
        AND ROUND(ar.duration) >0 AND ar.is_idle = false
        AND ar.week_id = ANY(ARRAY[some_data]) -- data size is 37
        AND ar.calendar_id = ANY(array[some_data]) -- data size is 16716
    GROUP by ar.user_id
) tmp;
```

And below is the explain result

```
Aggregate  (cost=31389954.72..31389954.73 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=252020.695..252020.695 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Group  (cost=31389032.69..31389922.37 rows=2588 width=4) (actual time=251089.270..252020.659 rows=351 loops=1)
        Group Key: ar.user_id
        ->  Sort  (cost=31389032.69..31389477.53 rows=177935 width=4) (actual time=251089.268..251776.202 rows=6993358 loops=1)
              Sort Key: ar.user_id
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 95672kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ar  (cost=609015.18..31371079.88 rows=177935 width=4) (actual time=1670.413..248939.440 rows=6993358 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((week_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[])) AND (user_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[])))
                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2081028
                    Filter: ((NOT is_idle) AND (round(duration) > '0'::double precision) AND (calendar_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[])))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 534017
                    Heap Blocks: exact=29551 lossy=313127
                    ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=609015.18..609015.18 rows=1357521 width=0) (actual time=1666.334..1666.334 rows=0 loops=1)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_index_only_scan_idx  (cost=0.00..272396.77 rows=6970353 width=0) (actual time=614.366..614.366 rows=7269830 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((week_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[])) AND (is_idle = false))
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on unique_key  (cost=0.00..336529.20 rows=9948573 width=0) (actual time=1041.999..1041.999 rows=14959355 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (user_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[]))
Planning time: 25.563 ms
Execution time: 252029.237 ms
```

I used distinct as well, and the result is the same.

**So my questions are below.**

1. The `ar_idx` contains `user_id`, but when searching for rows, why does it use the `unique_key` instead of the index I created?
2. I thought group by will not do the sort(that is why I did not choose `distinct`), but why does the sort happen in the explain analyze?
3. The running time is pretty long(more than 4 minutes). How do I make it faster? Is the index wrong? Or anything else I can do.

Be advised, the `ar` table **contains 51585203 rows**.

Any help will be appreciated. Thx.

---------------------------update--------------------------
After I created this index, everything goes really fast now. I don't understand why, anyone can explain this to me?

```
CREATE INDEX ar_1_idx
    ON public.ar USING btree
    (calendar_id, user_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

And I changed the old index to

```
CREATE INDEX ar_idx
    ON public.ar USING btree
    (week_id, calendar, user_id, activity_id, duration, on_taskness, start_time_local, end_time_local)  WHERE is_idle IS FALSE
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

-----updated analyze results-----------

```
 Aggregate  (cost=31216435.97..31216435.98 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=13206.941..13206.941 rows=1 loops=1)
      Buffers: shared hit=25940518 read=430315, temp read=31079 written=31079
      ->  Group  (cost=31215436.80..31216403.88 rows=2567 width=4) (actual time=12239.336..13206.894 rows=351 loops=1)
            Group Key: ar.user_id
            Buffers: shared hit=25940518 read=430315, temp read=31079 written=31079
            ->  Sort  (cost=31215436.80..31215920.34 rows=193417 width=4) (actual time=12239.334..12932.801 rows=6993358 loops=1)
                  Sort Key: ar.user_id
                  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 95664kB
                  Buffers: shared hit=25940518 read=430315, temp read=31079 written=31079
                  ->  Index Scan using ar_1_idx on activity_report ar  (cost=0.56..31195807.48 rows=193417 width=4) (actual time=0.275..10387.051 rows=6993358 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: ((calendar_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[])) AND (user_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[])))
                        Filter: ((NOT is_idle) AND (round(duration) > '0'::double precision) AND (week_id = ANY ('{some_data}'::integer[])))
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 590705
                        Buffers: shared hit=25940518 read=430315
    Planning time: 25.577 ms
    Execution time: 13217.611 ms
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Deleted the one in the dba. Sorry about this.

Comment: You could try to increase `work_mem` to make the bitmap scan more efficient. Did you run `analyze ar` after creating the indexes? How many rows does the condition `ar.is_idle = false` remove from the table? If that is a substantial part and you always have that condition, you could change the index to a partial index by removing `is_idle` from the column list and adding a `where not is_idle` to the index definition to only index rows where is_idle is false

Comment: You have obfuscated the names inconsistently and don't show all index definitions. I find it difficult to deal with that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thx for your comment, I tried to create a partial index., and it does not make it faster. However, when I create another index, everything goes really fast now. I updated the my post, can you tell me why>

Comment: You should include the new execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated my post again. thx

Comment: [Analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) your tables. It seems the significant difference between supposed (about 200,000) and actual (about 7,000,000) rows count in your execution plans.

Comment: @Abelisto I will do that next Monday. Unable to access office computer right now. But thx for your reply.

Comment: Additionally: change `ROUND(ar.duration) > 0` to `ar.duration >= 0.5` - it will enable to use index on `duration` column (if it exists and applicable).

Comment: @Abelisto thx for this information, This is new to me, I will try this next Monday. thx. And What about the user_id? Why that index was not used ?

Comment: Without having recent statistics on tables it is hard to say why DBMS preferred one execution plan and not another one.